# Transcendence of meromorphic function vs formal power series

Tags: complex-analysis, formal-power-series, meromorphic-functions, transcendence-theory

Consider the meromorphic function $f$ on $\mathscr D=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid|z|<1\}$ definied by $\displaystyle f(z)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{z^{2^n}}{z^{2^n}-\frac12}$. Obviously $f$ admits infinitely many poles (at $z=\frac1{\sqrt[2^n]2}$). So $f$ is transcendental on $\mathbb C(z)$. Now consider the formal power series $\displaystyle F=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{Z^{2^n}}{Z^{2^n}-\frac12}$. $F$ belongs to $\mathbb C((Z))$ since for every $n\in\mathbb N$, $\displaystyle \frac{Z^{2^n}}{Z^{2^n}-\frac12}$ belongs to $\mathbb C(Z)$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\mathrm{ord}_0\left(\frac{Z^{2^n}}{Z^{2^n}-\frac12}\right)=+\infty$.

My question now: How can one prove RIGOROUSLY that $F$ is transcedental on $\mathbb C(Z)$? There is no sense to talk about poles for this formal power series.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: not sure exactly what you mean but any formal algebraic relation $P(F,F',..F^{(k)})=0$ is clearly satisfied by $f$ too (since it's just a matter of finitely many coefficient relations) and that leads to a contradiction

Comment: That's the "clearly" that puts difficulties for me. Under the wood, there is the evaluation morphism in works, doesn't it?

Comment: why? - just write the identity $P(F,F',..F^{(k)})=0$ as a coefficient identity for each $n$ and then show that same coefficient identity is satisfied by $P(f,f',..f^{(k)})$ - eg if the equation is $zF+F'=0$ then the coefficients satisfy $a_1=0, a_{n-1}+(n+1)a_{n+1}=0, n \ge 1$ and that is also satisfied by the analytic $f$ satisfying $zf+f'=0$ etc; here this applies with the Laurent expansion of course

Comment: that means that if $f$ is meromorphic in the open set $U$, for every $z\in U$, $zf(z)+f'(z)=0$, right?

Comment: Yes - so in general any formal finite degree ode with rational coefficients gives just finitely many relations on coefficients so determine a meromorphic or analytic function as long as the radius of convergence is non zero or there is a convergent Laurent series; the problem is there as obviously there are formal series that satisfy such an ode but do not determine a complex function ($\sum n! z^n$) but if you start with a complex function, no problem